# Sending email with gmail in Symfony getting (3D =20) quoted-printable

Tags: php, symfony, gmail, mailer

I'm trying to send a html email using gmail transport using Symfony and Mailer. I have already sent it using the code bellow. The problem is that I can't get gmail to read it properly, still getting quoted-printable

```
<meta charset=3D"UTF-8" /><meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice=
-width, initial-scale=3D1.0, maximum-scale=3D1.0" /><meta name=3D"og:type" =
content=3D"website" />
```

I'm using this

```
$userEmail = $this->getUser()->getGoogleEmail();
$userGoogleAppPassword = $this->getUser()->getGoogleAppPassword();

$email = (new \Symfony\Component\Mime\Email())
    ->from($userEmail)
    ->to($clientDetails->getPrimaryEmail())
    ->subject($emailFound->getSubject())
    ->html($emailContent);

$email->setHeaders($email->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'));
$email->setHeaders($email->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'quoted-printable'));

$transport = new GmailSmtpTransport($userEmail, $userGoogleAppPassword);

$handler = new MessageHandler($transport);

$bus = new MessageBus([
    new HandleMessageMiddleware(new HandlersLocator([
        SendEmailMessage::class => [$handler],
    ])),
]);

$mailer_new = new Mailer($transport, $bus);
$mailer_new->send($email);
```

Tried setting the headers, encoded to base64 but then only partial data was send, like 1% of it. To send as base64 I used the php function (it worked) and set the Content-Transfer-Encoding to base64

Answer (score -1):

I was the problem, not symfony or mailer. The email was not properly done and wasn't made for gmail. The characters were in raw only. Remade the email myself and it's working perfectly

Comment: What does "made for" and "remade" mean?